# Migrate VMWare image to KVM

Tags: centos, port, vmware, windows-server-2012-r2, kvm

I am trying to migrate VMWare image with Windows 2012 R2 to KVM. I was able to get to point where I:

- merged all parts of vmdk into one file
- removed VMWare tools fro image
- converted vmdk to qcow2

  `qemu-img convert -o compat=0.10 -O qcow2 Windows2012-cl1.vmdk Windows2012-cl1.img`
- created new virtual machine in KVM
- added img drive to it
- booted VM in KVM

System was booting up but than it thrown an error

> Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart.

I tried to repair the system but it said that system drive is read-only. Where could be the problem? I also tried to boot from Win2012R2 ISO image to repair the system but it said that it cannot find system drive.

Host system: CentOS 6.5

Comment: Problem was old qemu in CentOS 6.5. When migrating to Ubuntu 14.04 there was no problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this was problem of CentOS qemu old version. It seems that CentOS 7 has still quite old qemu but I did not give it a try. Instead I tried Ubuntu 14.04 and it seems it is working. So anyone trying to do something like me I recommend checking version of qemu.

Answer (score 1):

Go to VmWares website and download their free converstion tool, use it to make OVF and OVA files, import them in the KVM virtual machine, you might need to use Virt-Tools, to move from OVF to KVM.

It looks like some of your data was comverted inproperly

Answer (score -1):

Amazon WebServices and Google Cloud has API's with SDK Tools to send your machine directly to the cloud.

I have been tested AWS VM Import and it is amazing.

Amazon WebServices VM Import:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

Google Cloud Compute:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/early-access