# Use RHEL KVM virt-v2v to convert vm from "vmware server 2.0.2"

Tags: import, migration, kvm, rhel6, vmware-server

I need to migrate about 8/10 "vmware server" vms (not esx/i) to rhel6.6 kvm but, from rhel documentation seems not possible because virt-v2v has to connect to "old" hypervisor for import vms...

Old hypervisor is the same host of new rhel kvm: old host is a windows 2003 and has the vmware server 2.0.2 installed on a hd, new hypervisor is rhel6.6 installed on another drive.

I think that virt-v2v cannot import vms from "vmware-server", and anyway, I can't have both hypervisor powered up at the same time.

Guests has heterogeneous os, windows 2003/2008 x86 / windows 2003/2008 x64 and linux x64 box/appliances.

There isn't a workaround for converting local (pre-imported) vm folders that contain vmware files (*.vmx and *.vmdk)?

I've already tried this solution and unfortunately does not works:
[Migrate VMWare image to KVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643901/migrate-vmware-image-to-kvm)

I'm forced to use rhel kvm because my hardware is incompatible with esx/i and I not care about other hypervisor products.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no sweat!

Simply import "*-flat.vmdk" file in virt-manager console, et voilà!

But, be sure to add [registry info](http://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/wiki/Migrate_Windows/MergeIDE.zip) to MS vm (if its has scsi disks) before import it into Qemu host.